# Kernel Errors in logwatch

Tags: centos, dedicated-server

We have a dedicated server running CentOS and Plesk.

We've had the following show up on our logwatch and wondered if it is anything we should worry about?

```
--------------------- Kernel Begin ------------------------ 

WARNING: Kernel Errors Present
Northbridge Error, node 1K8 ECC ...: 1 Time(s)

---------------------- Kernel End -------------------------
```

We've contacted the support team that we rent our server from but they don't seem to want to help us out without us paying their support team a fixed charge and even then they can't guarantee they would be able to find a solution to any potential problems.

Full log lines regarding Kernel error...

```
Jun 16 19:45:25 server88-208-217-241 kernel:  Northbridge Error, node 1<0>K8 ECC error.
Jun 16 19:45:25 server88-208-217-241 kernel: EDAC amd64 MC1: CE ERROR_ADDRESS= 0x2a3d553e0
Jun 16 19:45:25 server88-208-217-241 kernel: EDAC MC1: CE page 0x2a3d55, offset 0x3e0, grain 0, syndrome 0x5041, row 3, channel 0, label "": amd64_edac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you go into your logs (probably /var/log/messages) and retrieve the full error?

Comment: Updated original message with the 3 lines regardign kernel in the log.